# OSGi in Web-Container - The requested resource is not available (JSP File)

Tags: jsp, servlets, osgi, equinox, osgi-bundle

i have a problem. I want to use OSGi for a Website. I am pretty new to OSGi but i have read the basics and want to use the framework Equinox. For this i had read the Quick Start Guide from http://eclipse.org/equinox/ and bought and read the Book "OSGi and Equinox - Creating Highly Modular Java Systems"

But back to my problem. I downloaded the bridge.war from the equinox site and createt a first bundle with a servlet. The Activator look like this:

```
public void start(BundleContext bundleContext) throws Exception {
   Activator.context = bundleContext;
   httpServiceTracker = new HttpServiceTracker(context);
   httpServiceTracker.open();
}


public void stop(BundleContext bundleContext) throws Exception {
   Activator.context = null;
   httpServiceTracker.close();
   httpServiceTracker = null;
}

private class HttpServiceTracker extends ServiceTracker {

public HttpServiceTracker(BundleContext context) {
    super(context, HttpService.class.getName(), null);
}

public Object addingService(ServiceReference reference) {
    HttpService httpService = (HttpService) context.getService(reference);
    try {
    httpService.registerServlet("/index", new StartServlet(), null, null); //$NON-NLS-1$
    } catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return httpService;
}

public void removedService(ServiceReference reference, Object service) {
    HttpService httpService = (HttpService) service;
    httpService.unregister("/index"); //$NON-NLS-1$
    super.removedService(reference, service);
}
}
```

And my Servlet look like this:

protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    performTask(request, response);
    }

```
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException,
    IOException {
performTask(request, response);
}

private void performTask(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException,
    IOException {
RequestDispatcher RequestDispatcherview = request.getRequestDispatcher("test.jsp");
RequestDispatcherview.forward(request, response);
}
```

The JSP File is in the Folder /WebContent/ which is in the Bundle.
If i deploy the bundle into the bridge.war and try to open the site in a Browser, i always get the following:

[image]

I do not know how i can configure my Servlet or my Activator, that they will find the jsp file.
I tried to move the JSP File into the bridge.war but it does not help me to prevent this problem.

I guess i have to register the jsp file anywhere (maybe with `httpService.registerResources(arg0, arg1, arg2);`) but i do not know how i do this properly.

I hope you can help me.

Comment: You've registered your servlet under the "/index" context, shouldn't you have "index" in your URL somewhere?

Comment: If I open http://localhost:8080/bridge/index the servlet will be activated and in the servlet i try to dispatch the request to test.jsp but the servlet cannot find the jsp file.

Comment: How about the other way round, deploy your web application in a OSGi container instead. Either create your own setup of bundles or use a OSGi container like Apache Karaf.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally solved my Problem. I used extension points. Here is my plugin.xml:

```
<plugin>
    <extension point="org.eclipse.equinox.http.registry.httpcontexts">
        <httpcontext id="html">
            <resource-mapping path="/WebContent/static"/>
        </httpcontext>
    </extension>
    <extension point="org.eclipse.equinox.http.registry.resources">
        <resource alias="/webApp" httpcontextId="html"/>
    </extension>

    <extension point="org.eclipse.equinox.http.registry.httpcontexts">
        <httpcontext id="jsp">
            <resource-mapping path="/WebContent/dynamic"/>
        </httpcontext>
    </extension>
    <extension point="org.eclipse.equinox.http.registry.servlets">
        <servlet alias="/webApp/*.jsp" class="org.eclipse.equinox.jsp.jasper.registry.JSPFactory" httpcontextId="jsp"/>
        <servlet alias="/webApp/Login" class="webfiles.servlets.Login"/>
    </extension>
</plugin>
```

My Start and Stop methods in the Activator are looking like this:

Start:

```
 @Override
 public void start(BundleContext bundleContext) throws Exception {
    super.start(bundleContext);
    Activator.context = bundleContext;

    Bundle jettBundle = Platform.getBundle("org.eclips.equinox.http.jetty");
    Bundle httpRegistryBundle = Platform.getBundle("org.eclipse.equinox.http.registry");
    try {
        jettBundle.start();
        httpRegistryBundle.start();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO: handle exception
    }
 }
```

Stop:

```
@Override
public void stop(BundleContext bundleContext) throws Exception {
    super.stop(bundleContext);
    Activator.context = null;

    Bundle jettBundle = Platform.getBundle("org.eclips.equinox.http.jetty");
    Bundle httpRegistryBundle = Platform.getBundle("org.eclipse.equinox.http.registry");
    try {
        jettBundle.stop();
        httpRegistryBundle.stop();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO: handle exception
    }
 }
```

With this configuration i can use

```
RequestDispatcher dispatcher = req.getRequestDispatcher("/webApp/start.jsp");
dispatcher.forward(req, resp);
```

in my Servlet without problems.

I hope I can help others with the same Problem.